# Function in Matlab that returns indices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

How to write a function in Matlab that takes a matrix with a single 1 value in each column and returns the index of this 1.

Ex:
if the input is x=[0 0 1;1 0 0;0 1 0] it will return indices=[2 3 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the *row* index of the ones, this should do the trick:

```
[indices,~] = ind2sub(size(x),find(x))
```

Comment: @AmiraAkra I think Jonas's answer deserves to be the accepted one since theirs is cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

`find` is indeed the way to go

```
[indices,~] = find(x);
```

If you want to do it more cryptically, or hate `find` for some reason, you could also use `cumsum`:

```
indices = 4 - sum(cumsum(x,1),1);
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't realize `find` could automatically convert to subscripts.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the second output of [`max`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html):

```
[~, result] = max(x==1, [], 1);
```

A slightly more esoretic approach:

```
result = nonzeros(bsxfun(@times, x==1, (1:size(x,1)).'));
```

Comment: I find that @Jonas's first answer to best fit my situation

Comment: @AmiraAkra Sure. My intent was only to provide an alternative